# Why does removing a comma in this source file result in a scalar data in the HDF5 file?

Tags: python-3.x, h5py

```
 f = h5.File("image_data.h5", 'w')
 f["horizontal_min"] = horizontal_min,
 f["horizontal_max"] = horizontal_max,
 f["vertical_min"] = vertical_min,
 f["vertical_max"] =  vertical_max,
```

results in

```
horizontal_max           Dataset {1}
horizontal_min           Dataset {1}
vertical_max             Dataset {1}
vertical_min             Dataset {1}
```

But if the commas in the end of each of the lines is removed as in (output from h5ls):

```
 f = h5.File("image_data.h5", 'w')
 f["horizontal_min"] = horizontal_min
 f["horizontal_max"] = horizontal_max
 f["vertical_min"] = vertical_min
 f["vertical_max"] =  vertical_max
```

I get the following (output from h5ls):

```
  horizontal_max           Dataset {SCALAR}
  horizontal_min           Dataset {SCALAR}
  vertical_max             Dataset {SCALAR}
  vertical_min             Dataset {SCALAR}
```

Note that the data changed from `Dataset {1}` to `{SCALAR}`. Note the comma does not change the type as shown below:

```
  In [3]: type(5.0,)
  Out[3]: float

  In [4]: type(5.0)
  Out[4]: float
```

Why is this change happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an interactive `ipython` session:

```
In [66]: 1,                                                                                               
Out[66]: (1,)
In [67]: 1                                                                                                
Out[67]: 1
```

With the comma, the value is a `tuple`, which `h5py` will save as a 1d array.  Without the comma it's a scalar.

In Python a comma, is part of the `tuple` syntax; more important than the `()`.  It isn't a superfluous line ending.  (`;` is an optional line ender).

The correct way to do your last test:

```
In [71]: x=1,                                                                                             
In [72]: type(x)                                                                                          
Out[72]: tuple
In [73]: x=1                                                                                              
In [74]: type(x)                                                                                          
Out[74]: int
```

In `type(1,)` the comma is part of the arguments tuple. `type` takes 1 or 3 arguments.

> type(object_or_name, bases, dict)